Is the the expermental zoneless feature of Angular supported in storybook?
I am building a new app in Angular 18 using      provideExperimentalZonelessChangeDetection.
is this supported in Storybook 8.1?  I keep getting a compile error when I start the server because it si looking for zone.js

It would probaly help if you add more details, such as the error you get.

Storybook has a peer depdendency to zone.js. So no, it doesn't seem to be supported. You should open an issue on their issue tracker.

@JSONDerulo I have't found any code that uses Zones specifcally. You should be able to run a Zoneless app while still having zone as deps.

oh this an import : https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/535f7b9ba3849719e10e4b577f78660b77cdcaec/code/frameworks/angular/src/client/globals.ts#L28 so probably you won't be able to do real zoneless
